# Firefox shows wrong Emojis for some reason

Tags: firefox, emoji

Firefox shows the wrong emojis, but only on the page. In the source code, the correct emojis are shown (see screenshot).

This problem only affects Firefox, no other browser or app is affected. So it seems not to be an issue with the font. I already attempted to reinstall Firefox to no avail.

- MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021)
- macOS version 12.0.1
- Firefox 94.0.1 (64-bit)

[image]

Comment: can we have a link that redirects to this web page to try to reproduce it ?

Comment: Sure: https://emojipedia.org/people/ (not my website)

Comment: I am not having the same issue on a MBP 15" 2017 on macOS Monterey 12.0.1 and Firefox 94.0.1

Comment: Then it may be a Firefox issue. Will check if I can issue a bug report.

Comment: Bug report created: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1742418

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by a browser extension. The issue disappeared after disabling all extensions and restarting Firefox. Unfortunately, even after enabling all extensions again the issue is no longer reproducible, so I couldn't pinpoint the exact culprit.